# best way to check if files have been processed

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

E: My initial Title was very misleading.

I have a SQL server with a database and I have around 10,000 excel files in a directory. The files contain values I need to copy into the DB with new excel files being added on a daily basis.  Additionally, each file contains a field "finished" with a boolean value, that expresses if the file is ready to be copied to the DB. However, the filename is not connected to it's contend. Only the content of file contains primary keys and filed names corresponding to the DB's keys and field names.

Checking if the file's content is already in the DB by comparing the primary key over and over is not feasible, since opening the files is far too slow. I could however check if files are already in the DB initially and write the result in a file (say copied.txt), so it simply holds the filenames of all already copied files. The real service could then load this file's content into a dictionary (dict1) with the filename as the key and with no value (I think hash tables are the fastest for comparative operations), then store the filenames of all existing excel files in the dir in a second dictionary (dict2) and compare both dictionary and create a list of all files that are in dict2 but not in dict1. I would then iterate through the list (should usually only contain around 10-20 files), checking if the files are flagged as "ready to be copied" and copy the values to the database. Finally, I would add this file's name to dict1 and store it back to the copied.txt file.

My idea is to run this python script as a service that loops as long as there are files to work with. When it can't find files to copy from, it should wait for x seconds (maybe 45) than do it all over.

This my best concept so far. Is there a faster/ more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Use watcher https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

Answer (score 1):

It just came back to my mind that sets only contain unique elements and thus are the best data type for a comparison like this. It is a data type that I hardly know but now I can see how useful it can be.

The part of the code that is related to my original question is in Part 1-3:
The program:
1. loads file names from a file to a set
2. loads file names from the filesystem/ a certain dir + subdirs to a set
3. creates a list of the difference of the two sets
4. iterates through  all remaining files
 looks, if they have been flagged as "finalized",
 than for each row:
  creates a new record in the database
  and adds values to given record (one by one)
5. adds the processed file's name to the file of filenames.

It does so every 5 minutes. This is completely fine for my purpose.

I am very new to coding so sorry for my dilettantish approach. At least it works so far.

```
#modules
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as db
import xlwings as xw
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime, date
from pathlib import Path
import time
import sys

#constants
tick_time_seconds = 300

line = ("################################################################################### \n")
pathTodo = "c:\\myXlFiles\\**\\*"
pathDone = ("c:\\Done\\")
pathError = ("c:\\Error\\")

sqlServer = "MyMachine\\MySQLServer"
sqlDriver = "{SQL Server}"
sqlDatabase="master"
sqlUID="SA"
sqlPWD="PWD" 

#functions
def get_list_of_files_by_extension(path:str, extension:str) -> list:
    """Recieves string patch and extension;
    gets list of files with corresponding extension in path;
    return list of file with full path."""
    fileList = glob.glob(path+extension, recursive=True)
    if not fileList:
        print("no found files")
    else:
        print("found files")
    return fileList

def write_error_to_log(description:str, errorString:str, optDetails=""):
    """Recieves strings description errorstring and opt(ional)Details;
    writes the error with date and time in logfile with the name of current date;
    return nothing."""
    logFileName = str(date.today())+".txt"
    optDetails = optDetails+"\n"
    dateTimeNow = datetime.now()
    newError = "{0}\n{1}\n{2}{3}\n".format(line, str(dateTimeNow), optDetails, errorString)
    print(newError)
    with open(Path(pathError, logFileName), "a") as logFile:
        logFile.write(newError)

def sql_connector():
    """sql_connector: Recieves nothing;
    creates a connection to the sql server (conncetion details sould be constants);
    returns a connection."""
    return db.connect("DRIVER="+sqlDriver+"; \
                        SERVER="+sqlServer+"; \
                        DATABASE="+sqlDatabase+"; \
                        UID="+sqlUID+"; \
                        PWD="+sqlPWD+";")

def sql_update_builder(dbField:str, dbValue:str, dbKey:str) -> str:
    """ sql_update_builder: takes strings dbField, dbValue and dbKey;
    creates a sql syntax command with the purpose to update the value of the
    corresponding field with the corresponding key;
    returns a string with a sql command."""
    return "\
            UPDATE [tbl_Main] \
            SET ["+dbField+"]='"+dbValue+"' \
            WHERE ((([tbl_Main].MyKey)="+dbKey+"));"

def sql_insert_builder(dbKey: str) -> str:
    """ sql_insert_builder: takes strings  dbKey;
    creates a sql syntax command with the purpose to create a new record;
    returns a string with a sql command."""
    return "\
            INSERT INTO [tbl_Main] ([MyKey])\
            VALUES ("+dbKey+")"

def append_filename_to_fileNameFile(xlFilename):
    """recieves anywthing xlFilename;
    converts it to string  and writes the filename (full path) to a file;
    returns nothing."""
    with open(Path(pathDone, "filesDone.txt"), "a") as logFile:
        logFile.write(str(xlFilename)+"\n")
###################################################################################
###################################################################################
# main loop
while __name__ == "__main__":

    ###################################################################################
    """ 1. load filesDone.txt into set"""
    listDone = []
    print(line+"reading filesDone.txt in "+pathDone)
    try:
        with open(Path(pathDone, "filesDone.txt"), "r") as filesDoneFile:
            if filesDoneFile:
                print("file contains entries")
                for filePath in filesDoneFile:
                    filePath = filePath.replace("\n","")
                    listDone.append(Path(filePath))
    except Exception as err:
        errorDescription = "failed to read filesDone.txt from {0}".format(pathDone)
        write_error_to_log(description=errorDescription, errorString=str(err))
        continue
    else: setDone = set(listDone)
    ###################################################################################
    """ 2. load filenames of all .xlsm files into set"""
    print(line+"trying to get list of files in filesystem...")
    try: 
        listFileSystem = get_list_of_files_by_extension(path=pathTodo, extension=".xlsm")
    except Exception as err:
        errorDescription = "failed to read file system "
        write_error_to_log(description=errorDescription, errorString=str(err))
        continue
    else:
        listFiles = []
        for filename in listFileSystem:
            listFiles.append(Path(filename))
        setFiles = set(listFiles)
    ###################################################################################
    """ 3. create list of difference of setMatchingFiles and setDone"""
    print(line+"trying to compare done files and files in filesystem...")
    setDifference = setFiles.difference(setDone)
    ###################################################################################
    """ 4. iterate thru list of files """

    for filename in setDifference:
        """ 4.1 try: look if file is marked as "finalized=True";
        if the xlfile does not have sheet 7 (old ones)
        just add the xlfilename to the xlfilenameFile"""
        try:
            print("{0}trying to read finalized state ... of {1}".format(line, filename))
            filenameClean = str(filename).replace("\n","")
            xlFile = pd.ExcelFile(filenameClean)
        except Exception as err:
                errorDescription = "failed to read finalized-state from {0} to dataframe".format(filename)
                write_error_to_log(description=errorDescription, errorString=str(err))
                continue
        else:
            if "finalized" in xlFile.sheet_names:
                dataframe = xlFile.parse("finalized")
                print("finalized state ="+str(dataframe.iloc[0]["finalized"]))
                if dataframe.iloc[0]["finalized"] == False:
                    continue
            else: 
                append_filename_to_fileNameFile(filename) #add the xlfilename to the xlfilenameFile"
                continue
        ###################################################################################
        """ 4.2 try: read values to dataframe"""
        try:
            dataframe = pd.read_excel(Path(filename), sheet_name=4)
        except Exception as err:
                errorDescription = "Failed to read values from {0} to dataframe".format(filename)
                write_error_to_log(description=errorDescription, errorString=str(err))
                continue
        ###################################################################################
        """ 4.2 try: open connection to database"""
        print("{0}Trying to open connection to database {1} on {2}".format(line, sqlDatabase, sqlServer))
        try:
            sql_connection = sql_connector() #create connection to server
            stuff = sql_connection.cursor()
        except Exception as err:
            write_error_to_log(description="Failed to open connection:", errorString=str(err))
            continue
        ###################################################################################
        """ 4.3 try: write to database"""
        headers = list(dataframe) #copy header from dataframe to list; easier to iterate
        values = dataframe.values.tolist() #copy values from dataframe to list of lists [[row1][row2]...]; easier to iterate
        for row in range(len(values)): #iterate over lines
            dbKey = str(values[row][0]) #first col is key
            sqlCommandString = sql_insert_builder(dbKey=dbKey)
            """ 4.3.1 firts trying to create (aka insert) new record in db ..."""
            try: 
                print("{0}Trying insert new record with the id {1}".format(line, dbKey))
                stuff.execute(sqlCommandString)
                sql_connection.commit()
                print(sqlCommandString)
            except Exception as err:
                sql_log_string = " ".join(sqlCommandString.split()) #get rid of whitespace in sql command
                write_error_to_log(description="Failed to create new record in DB:", errorString=str(err), optDetails=sql_log_string)
            else: #if record was created add the values one by one:
                print("{0}Trying to add values to record with the ID {1}".format(line, dbKey))
            """ 4.3.2 ... than trying to add the values one by one"""
            for col in range(1, len(headers)): #skip col 0 (the key)
                dbField = str(headers[col]) #field in db is header in the excel sheet
                dbValue = str(values[row][col]) #get the corresponding value
                dbValue = (dbValue.replace("\"","")).replace("\'","") #getting rid of ' and " to prevent trouble with the sql command
                sqlCommandString = sql_update_builder(dbField, dbValue, dbKey) # calling fuction to create a sql update command string
                try: #try to commit the sql command
                    stuff.execute(sqlCommandString)
                    sql_connection.commit()
                    print(sqlCommandString)
                except Exception as err:
                    sql_log_string = " ".join(sqlCommandString.split()) #get rid of whitespace in sql command
                    write_error_to_log(description="Failed to add values in DB:", errorString=str(err), optDetails=sql_log_string)
        append_filename_to_fileNameFile(filename)

    print(line)
    # wait for a certain amount of time
    for i in range(tick_time_seconds, 0, -1):
                sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(i))
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(1)
                sys.stdout.flush()
    print(line)
    #break # this is for debuggung
```